# BDD with NBehave with MSTest TDD

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, mstest, bdd

Hi friends,

I want to use NBehave with Visual studio unit testing frame work. I have tried to dig into many links but most of them explains NBehave with MBUnit.

Can any one help me to find any resources to use NBehave with VS Test?

Comment: Have you considered using a different BDD framework, or are you forced to use NBehave? If you are at the stage of investigating BDD frameworks I'd recommend SpecFlow, as there are lots of examples of how to get this working with VS Test. Also it has a lot more support available e.g. 9 questions are tagged with NBehave on StackOverflow, versus 388 tagged with SpecFlow.

Answer (score 1):

I used to really like nbehave and I think it is a great product but it has one simple flaw. It has a custom test runner and therefore nothing else integrates with it as easily as the more common used frameworks.

As @Fresh points out in the comments, SpecFlow is the far more commonly used framework for plain text specification testing on DotNet. I've chosen to use it on my most recent projects because you just use the nUnit or mstest test runner of your choice, which means instant integration with tools such as ReSharper, TeamCity, dotcover, nDepend, and of course the integrated test runner in Vs2012 and later.